# How to implement a validator in an Angular Form

Tags: angular, validation

I'm implementing a React Forms custom validator in Angular. I have 8 fields, which two I would like to verify if date is less than other.
I don't know why, but aren't returning the errors to the form.

Could someone help me to see if I'm doing something wrong?

My goal is, show the div when dateLessThanValidator is true

the JS

```
this.scheduleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  searchText: [this.searchText],
  codEnd: [this.workschedule.codEnd, Validators.required],
  dataInicio: [this.workschedule.dataInicio, Validators.required],
  dataFim: [this.workschedule.dataFim, Validators.required],
  periodo: [this.workschedule.periodo, Validators.required],
  justificativa: [this.workschedule.justificativa, Validators.required],
  totalColaboradores: [this.workschedule.totalColaboradores],
  totalTerceiros: [this.workschedule.totalTerceiros]
},
  {
    validator: [dateLessThanValidator]
  });

export function dateLessThanValidator(c: AbstractControl) {
debugger;
const dataInicio = c.get('dataInicio');
const dataFim = c.get('dataFim');

if (!dataInicio || !dataFim) { return null; }

return (new Date(dataInicio.value) > new Date(dataFim.value)) ? c.setErrors({  'dateLessThan': true }) : null;
};
```

The HTML

```
    <div *ngIf="scheduleForm.errors && scheduleForm.errors.dateLessThan" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12">A data de Início deve ser maior do que a data Fim</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a cross-field validation. The parameter of a cross-field validation is not a FormControl, but a FormGroup. Please change the signature of your function. If necessary double check with https://medium.com/@realTomaszKula/angular-cross-field-validation-d94e0d063b61